# Iterating with Map with Keys vs Values . Which is more efficient?

Tags: apex, performance, cpulimit

Iterating with Map with Keys vs Values :

As in Apex we need to write code efficiently for avoiding memory issues and CPU time limit everywhere, I need to understand how to iterate over a map efficiently.
Some say by values and some by keys.

```
for (Object o : map.values()){
//your logic
}
```

or

```
for (Id eachOLIId : mapItems.keySet()) {
OpportunityLineItem lineITem = mapItems.get(eachOLIId);
// your logic
}
```

Comment: Depends on the scenario. In your example I would say by value. If by using values you would have to perform additional logic to filter I would say use keys. In your case there’s is no need for a map at all and you could just stick with a list.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, following `for` loop is iterating over a list which can have duplicate values.

```
for (Object o : map.values()){
//your logic
}
```

And below you are iterating over a `Set<Id>()` which does not contain duplicates.

```
for (Id eachOLIId : mapItems.keySet()) {
OpportunityLineItem lineITem = mapItems.get(eachOLIId);
// your logic
}
```

Secondly, if you have multiple inner `for` loops then that `inner` for loops can be eliminated with the use of `map`. and that moment you will get performance benefit and hence minimize CPU limit also.

Basically, how you are putting your logic to achieve your business case depends on scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're noticing a performance issue, use whichever you prefer. The difference in performance is negligible in most cases. The only time you definitely want to use `values` is if you have a large map with a [custom key](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm) that has a high collision rate (and if you have that problem, you should be optimizing your custom key).